# Trouble translating Pandas methods to work with PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm new to PySpark and currently trying to use a Spark cluster to run some logic over a dataframe which is ~2GB. My code looks like the following and I didn't have a problem with it when I was using just Pandas on a subset of the data.

```py
data = df.groupby("NAMES").apply(lambda x: function(x, "GRADE"))
```

I'm throwing the following error when I use `groupBy()` or just `groupby()` Can someone help me figure out how to translate Pandas method to work with `PySpark`?

```py
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-23-a8b90935b1b1> in <module>
    ----> 1 data = df.groupby("NAMES").apply(lambda x: function(x, "GRADE"))
    
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

In addition, I'm using the following before my function and will comment it out. Assume the logic is correct and I'm using vanilla Python3.

```py
import os
import pyspark
from tqdm import tqdm
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf("NAMES string", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def function(x, col):
      # logic goes here...

    return list1, list2, list3
```

Update**
Didn't know that Spark does not like Null values. Weird...

Comment: with the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'`, it seems that `df` is not a dataframe. How did you create `df`?

Comment: df = spark.read.csv(path=path, header=True). I think the issue might be that the dataset has null values?

Comment: I guess you assign something else to the variable df, this command line seems ok. do you perform the groupBy directly after the read.csv or you transform and/or show you dataframe between?

Comment: A common mistake is to do something like `df = df.show(10)`. then df is NoneType

Comment: Interesting @Ben.T. So you don't save to variables in PySpark? I removed it and now it worked. Was df_clean = df.na.drop(how="any").show() and worked with  df.na.drop(how="any").show()

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: 
ValueError: Invalid udf: the udf argument must be a pandas_udf of type GROUPED_MAP.

Comment: It is really related to the method `show`, by design if returns `None`. you can do `df = df.na.drop()` to reassign df without the nan values. but `show` should not be assign. Regarding your new error, I suggest either you delete this question and ask a new one, or you edit this question with more details :)